# Missing keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, shortcut

Been using Mac now for about a month and still looking for 2 basic shortcuts.

1. Windows equivalent for "Delete" - where it deletes the character in front of the cursor.
   Currently, "delete" on my mac acts more as "backspace". Tried <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>but that just creates bookmark on chrome.
2. Word processing text navigation - windows equivalent of <kbd>^ Control</kbd>  + Arrow keys to jump between words, separated by spaces. 
   I'd like to be able to combine this with <kbd>^ Control</kbd> <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>  + Arrow to select multiple words.

On the Mac, using <kbd>^ Control</kbd>  or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>move entire lines, and <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes full lines/sentences.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌫ Delete</kbd> or <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for keyboards without an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key

As for moving between words, use the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> modifier.  Example, <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>➞</kbd> to move to the word to the right.

There's an excellent list of all the [predefined shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201236) on Apple's Support site.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That link is fantastic, not sure why I couldn't find it by searching earlier. Control + D works perfect. Option + Left or Right moves screens. Is there a way to change this? I also imagine that Shift + Option + Left or RIght would select entire words?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a few words to @Allan's excellent answer, there seems to be an almost unlimited set of keyboard shortcuts - shortcuts that aren't listed in the [predefined shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201236) list. There is, for example another entire page of [keyboard shortcuts dedicated to the `terminal` app](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/keyboard-shortcuts-trmlshtcts/mac). Then there's [MacPaw's Ultimate List...](https://macpaw.com/how-to/mac-keyboard-shortcuts) which is interesting & useful. And there are [many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=ALL+mac+keyboard+shortcuts)...

Oddly (at least to me) one that seems to have been omitted from some of the many [macos keyboard shortcut lists](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mac+keyboard+shortcuts&t=ffnt&ia=cheatsheet) is the one I use perhaps most frequently in my browser apps (Firefox, Chrome & Safari at least) for switching between browser tabs: forward=<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, backward=<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>